# How do I run multiple instances of a build (VS-C#)?

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studios 2017, is there a hot key to run multiple builds of a console application besides doing -> (project -> Debug -> Start new instance), this way takes forever when trying to run 10 or so instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own keyboard shortcuts using the Keyboard Shortcuts Editor.

Below is the link for the same:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings

Hope this helps!
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, it works. For the 2017 version they moved keyboard shortcuts to [link]https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138531.aspx. This will save so much time!